# nested less styles not apply for angular select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I was tried to apply custom less for select2 working fine, but when I try with nested less styles not applying those styles Since the select2 dropdown will create out of the particular div. I have more than one select2 so there is no possible to add class to body.

Actually I need some custom style if parent element have some class.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer,

`element.select2({containerCssClass: "classA", dropdownCssClass: "classB"});`